# Is a ship a statically indeterminate structure?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structures

We can consider that a ship is a complex implementation of forces on a beam, that a ship is essentially a beam.

The support is the buoyancy force which is continuous but it takes different values depending on the geometry of the ship, on the surface that sees the water.

The loads also differ along the length of the ship.

Could we name this a statically indeterminate structure?

Comment: If it is indeterminate, will it sink?

Comment: @Solar Mike Better not i am inside a ship now

Comment: Statically it is unstable, though all the internal stresses can be calculated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand to TigerGuy's answer, the distribution of buoyancy forces in a ship can be considered in a similar way to beams on an elastic foundation.

[image]

**Figure  Beam resting on two-parameter elastic foundation (source : [I.Teodorou](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Beams-on-Elastic-Foundation.-The-Simplified-Teodoru/a01619cc2215d0e1c7774b8ab25d99282d67a67f/figure/2))**

as you can see, this can be simplified by an infinite number of springs.

In that sense the beam is an statically indeterminate structure.

Answer (score 2):

A ship is a statically indeterminate structure. Because:

> the static equilibrium equations – force and moment equilibrium conditions – are insufficient for determining the internal forces and reactions on that structure.

Quote from Wikipedia. [source](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Statically_indeterminate)

One rule of thumb is when the support reactions and member forces are depending on the structure configuration, or its member section properties, the compatibility in deformations, that structure is indeterminate. A ship is an example of this.

A simple three-member triangular truss becomes indeterminate as soon as a vertical redundant member is added from the top vertex to the middle of the bottom member.

A ship by design has many structural redundant members. Thus it is an indeterminate structure.

An example of an indeterminate beam. It has 4 unknowns, but only three equilibrium equations. Details in the article.

[image: indeterminate beam.]

Answer (score 1):

It is statically indeterminate because it is a dynamic system.  Ships move; therefore, they are not static.

Comment: Thanks, but during the time that is not moving at port?

Comment: is there no wind, no waves, no currents?  It's a dynamic system.

Comment: @TigerGuy How about a toy boat in a bowl in a closed room with no ventillation